# How to style nested components in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

Imagine I have a wrapper component:

```
<app-my-wrapper>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-my-wrapper>
```

The router outlet injects one of following components:

```
<app-page1></app-page1>
<app-page2></app-page2>
<app-page3></app-page3>
```

I want `app-page1`, `app-page2` and `app-page3` to have some special styles, but **only if** inside `app-my-wrapper`.

I'd normally do something like this:

**my-wrapper.component.scss**

```
:host ::ng-deep .page {
   /* some styles */
}
```

According to [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), `/deep/`, `>>>`, and `::ng-deep` are deprecated.

What would be the proper way of giving the children components some extra styles depending on the parent component?

Comment: My understanding is that `::ng-deep` is the way to do it until Angular proposes something else. See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160) and [this other issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17867).

Answer (score 2):

You can disable view encapsulation for your current component:

Simply add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component decorator.

See https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation for more details.